# Create a program that prompts the student with a sum such as What is 10 times 6?

Tags: javascript

The program prompts the student with a question such as What is 10 times 6? The student then types the answer into a text field and the program checks whether the student’s answer is correct.[This is what the code is supposed to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LmaR.png). This is the code that i have:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Learning to Multiply Website</title>
<style>
    label,
    input {
        width: 120px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    label {
        width: 240px;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
        margin-top: 2px;
    }
    br {
        clear: left;
    }
    .button {
        width: 120px;
        background: rgba(144, 255, 246, 0.42);
        color: #0000a0;
        padding: 5px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: 250px;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var num1, num2, res;
    num1 = Math.floor(1+ Math.random() *12); 
    num2 = Math.floor(1+ Math.random() *12);
 document.writeln("<h1>" + num1 + " times " + num2 +" ?</h1>");
 res = num1 * num2;
 document.writeln ("<h1>" + res + " </h1>");

 document.getElementById

 </script>

 </head>

 <body>
  <h1>Learning to Multiply Website</h1>
  <form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="#">
    <label>What is </label>
    <input id="inputVal" name="inputVal" type="text" />
    <br>
    <label>The answer is</label>
    <input name="outputVal" id="outputVal" type="text" />
    <br>
    <input class="button" name="Check My Anwer" type="button" value="Check My    Answer" onclick="Check My Answer" />                                                                         
</form>
```

[And this is what is produces:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex9Ug.png)

Does anyone know how I can get the sum to go into the 'What is' box i have created. It is currently above the table i have created.

Comment: It appears there because you are just writing it out to the screen above where the HTML is rendered. You need to set the value of the textbox equal to your result.

Comment: How do you set the value of the textbox equal to your result?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
document.getElementById('inputVal').value = num1 + ' times ' + num2;
```

The `.value` property of an input element contains its value and can be set to change its value.

For non-input elements (e.g. `<div>`, `<p>`) the property would be `.innerHTML`

In actual webpages you should (almost) never use `document.write` or `document.writeln`. Instead, use `document.getElementById` to find an existing HTML element in the DOM tree and then use `.innerHTML` to set its contents (or `.value` for form inputs).

Answer (score 0):

After calculating the result into `res`, you can place it into the input field like so:

```
document.getElementById('outputVal').value = res;
```

However, the way your entire code is written right now, it is likely not going to work. This is because the javascript code between the `<script>` tags executes before all the DOM elements are loaded, including the element with id `outputVal`. Basically, at the point in time when this line is reached, there is no element with the id `outputVal` on the page.

To check that the DOM elements are loaded use:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    /*
    your code here
    */
});
```

The code will execute once all the DOM elements have loaded.

Generally, it is recommended to separate your Javascript and CSS code from HTML, and load them externally. You can do this by writing your Javascript code in a separate .js file, and place `<script src="myscript.js"><script>` in your HTML `<head>`.

Comment: I've tried adding this to the code but it doesn't seem to work